# AngularJS - multiple $http recursive calls in a loop

Tags: angularjs, ajax, http, asynchronous, recursion

We have a hierarchy of people like below:

```
M1
    A1
        AA1
            AAA1
    A2
        AA2
            AAA2
    A3
        AA3
M2
    B1
        BB1
            BBB1
    B2
        BB2     
M3
    C1
    C2
    C3
```

Initially, the hierarchy will be collapsed and so it looks like as below:

```
+ M1
+ M2
+ M3
```

There is an Expand All option, upon clicking it should expand all levels in async manner. We have code as below to achieve that:

```
function expandAll() {
    expandAll(mainDirects);           
}

function expandAll(directs){
    if(!directs){
        return;
    }
    _.each(directs, function (direct){
        if(direct.IsManager){
            direct.expand().then(function(node){
                expandAll(node.directs)
            });
        }
    });
}
```

`direct.expand()` is a method which makes an http call to a service to get directs of the given manager. The issue we have run into is that only the call of last direct at given level is hitting the service for all the directs of that level i.e. for M1 and M2 the hierarchy which is getting displayed is that of M3 (as seen below). Since it's a recursion, same thing is happening for further levels so heirarchy of A1 and A2 is that of A3.

```
M1
    C1
        AA3
    C2 
        AA3
    C3
        AA3
M2
    C1
        BB2
    C2
        BB2
    C3     
M3
    C1
    C2
    C3
```

Looks like `$http` queues up all the requests and only the last one gets executed N times. Any idea how to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Your code looks fine, Can you show us direct.expand() method

Comment: Expand code is like this: `function expand() {
            var node = this;
            var deferred = $q.defer();
         
            if (node.IsManager) {
    getDirectsList(node.Alias, node.level).then(function (response) {
       node.DirectReportees = response;
       deferred.resolve(node);
   });
            }
            else{
                deferred.resolve(node);
            }
            return deferred.promise;
        }`

Comment: getDirectList eventually makes an $http call through a facade i.e. as: `get = function (u, p, h) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
                $http({
                    method: 'GET',
                    url: u,
                    params: p,
                    headers: h
                }).then(function (response) {
                    deferred.resolve(response.data.Result);
                }, function (response) {
                    deferred.reject(response);
                });
                return deferred.promise;

        };`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use following

```
var k = 0;
_.each(directs, function (direct){
    (function(k) {
        if(direct.IsManager){
            direct.expand().then(function(node){
                expandAll(node.directs);
                k++;
            });
        }
    })(k);
});
```

instead of

```
_.each(directs, function (direct){
    if(direct.IsManager){
        direct.expand().then(function(node){
            expandAll(node.directs)
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @AliRazaGhori! I tried out but in vain. If you can explain the solution. Also, k is incrementing inside a different closure so it is always zero.